# Не могу очистить input после выбора в typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть проблема в очистке формы после выбора элемента в *typeahead.js*. Прилагаю код слушателя событий:

```
.on('typeahead:select', function (e, datum) {
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).val('');
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

В чём может быть ошибка? Через консоль разработчика все спокойно чистится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.on('typeahead:select', function (e, datum) {
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).typeahead('setQuery', '');
    e.preventDefault(); })
}
```

Comment: Или вместо `setQuery` там `val` не помню точно